# Null value when finding game object by tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, test-runner

I am writting test cases for a Unity Project. I wanted to create a instance of a Monobehaviour class.

**Problem:** 
Null value when I am trying to find game object with the tag.

**Code:**

```
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator DummyTestWithEnumeratorPasses() {
    GameObject  dummyController = GameObject.FindWithTag("dummyControllerTag");
    Debug.Log (dummyController);  // Null always.
    yield return null;
}
```

**Snapshot:**

[image]

**EDIT**:

After the comments, here is my new code that matches the tag name:

```
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator DummyTestWithEnumeratorPasses() {
    GameObject  CUIController = GameObject.FindWithTag("CUIControllerTag");
    Debug.Log (CUIController);  // Null always.
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: The most obvious thing would be that there is no GameObject with the tag `dummyControllerTag` in the scene, but I guess you have checked that, right?

Comment: Do you have any object with the "dummyControllerTag" tag? If so can please add a screenshot of this object to prove it. Also, the find function cannot be used t find in-active objects. Is your object active?

Comment: Have you already instantiated an object with that tag?

Comment: I have checked the Tag name. Its fine @Ian H

Comment: Added the screenshot. @Programmer

Comment: I voted to close this question as "typographical error" because the name in the tag does not match the name in your code. *"CUIControllerTag"* is **not** the-same as *"dummyControllerTag"*

Comment: Changed @Programmer

Comment: So does it still not work?